# Attempting to space out multi-level lists causes mis-alignment of child elements

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

Say I'm entering a list, like so:

```
* Item 1
 * SubItem 1a
 * SubItem 1b
* Item 2
 * SubItem 2a
 * SubItem 2b
```

As you'd expect, this results in:

- Item 1

  - SubItem 1a
  - SubItem 1b
- Item 2

  - SubItem 2a
  - SubItem 2b

But, if I add an extra line before `* Item 2` in the source (to add spacing to the list and try to make it less crowded and so hopefully more readable), then it looks like this:

- Item 1

  - SubItem 1a
  - SubItem 1b
- Item 2

  - SubItem 2a
  - SubItem 2b

(Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oth8k.png) for reference, but essentially the child elements are aligned *down* with a gap between them and their parent entry)

A quick glance at Firebug seems to show that the `Item 2` text is wrapped in `<p>` tags, which imposes a 1em bottom margin, but there is no `<p>` wrapper present in the non-spaced version.

I like to try and space my lists out to make them more pleasant, so I've noticed that this issue has been around for a while, but I wonder if we could either have this fixed (so that child items are aligned up to their parent and the gap remains) or maybe just remove the additional spacing entirely (at least avoiding the abnormally spaced lists)?

Comment: see Markdown Babelmark results here: http://goo.gl/NRgTE

Comment: Sorry, @Jeff, but I think the point you're making is that the HTML that is being produced by the site is correct? That's fine, but regardless the rendering still looks wrong to me... and like all good (or possibly bad...) requests of this nature, I ultimately don't *really* care what the fix is, where the blame lies or even what's actually wrong; just that the perceived issue goes away as a result (or is at least declined, for closure). :)

Answer (score 9):

Well, in the meantime, here's a workaround which keeps the outer list as one single list (where [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85622/attempting-to-space-out-multi-level-lists-causes-mis-alignment-of-child-elements/85742#85742) yields two separate lists):

```
1. Item 1
 * SubItem 1a
 * SubItem 1b<br><br>
1. Item 2
 * SubItem 2a
 * SubItem 2b
```

produces

1. Item 1

   - SubItem 1a
   - SubItem 1b
2. Item 2

   - SubItem 2a
   - SubItem 2b

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution if you don't mind ending up with two separate lists (fine for bullet lists, not so much for numbered lists):

```
- Item 1
  - SubItem 1a
  - SubItem 1b

<!-- hey there sailor -->

- Item 2
  - SubItem 2a
  - SubItem 2b
```

produces

- Item 1

  - SubItem 1a
  - SubItem 1b

- Item 2

  - SubItem 2a
  - SubItem 2b

Answer (score -1):

You say you want to "add spacing to the list and try to make it less crowded and so hopefully more readable." That's means you want to *restyle* your list, which is a matter of CSS. If the generated HTML markup is semantically correct, there's no need to don't mess with it.

Try this CSS, for example:

```
ul { padding: 0; margin: 0 0 1em 2em; list-style: disc; }
ul ul { margin-bottom: 0 }
p { margin: 0 0 0.5em }

ul + ul { margin-top: 2em } /* <-- try changing this */
```

[See this example on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Uansq/)

Comment: We don't support user CSS to style posts here...