# Spacing oddity between lists when lists are found consecutively

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown-rendering

Markdown:

```
1. Item 1
1. Item 2

1. Item 3
1. Item 4
1. Item 5
```

[Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSsW3.png) outputted as:

1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3
4. Item 4
5. Item 5

The visual gap after item 3 appears to be an error. If I stick anything non-list between items 2 and 3 (say, `<!-- . -->`) the symptom disappears.

Also happens with a nested list:

```
1. Item 1
1. Item 2
    - Sub Item

1. Item 3
```

...[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXhw4.png) showing as:

1. Item 1
2. Item 2

   - Sub Item
3. Item 3

The same when explicitly adding blank lines for readability, but only for sub lists that have a single item, not for sub lists that have multiple items. Note that, despite the additional blank lines, Markdown correctly sees this as a single list, and the browser correctly increases the numbered items for that:

```
1. Item 1

    1. Sub Item 1a

    1. Sub Item 1b

1. Item 2

    - Sub Item 2a

1. Item 3

    - Sub Item 3a

    - Sub Item 3b

1. Item 4
```

Which [now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljXgH.png) renders as:

1. Item 1

   1. Sub Item 1a
   2. Sub Item 1b
2. Item 2

   - Sub Item 2a
3. Item 3

   - Sub Item 3a
   - Sub Item 3b
4. Item 4

Comment: Hmm, the specific trigger causing this seems to have intentionally been put into place, although I can't immediately understand why. If it's resolved, you'll get a single list with five items and no mysterious space - is that what you were expecting?

Comment: I added another example; something similar bit me on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111421/what-is-downvoting-really-for/111427#111427 if you look at the spacing between all the list items except after the sub-list.

Comment: @Tim: It should be two lists, with one gap between items 2 and 3.

Comment: @Tomalak, I raised a [similar issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85622/) a while back, and there's a few additional work-arounds listed in answers there which you might find helpful.

Comment: @DMA57361: I don't need a workaround; I am posting because I want it to be fixed! Surely the "by design" should be removed if nobody can figure out why this is so.

Comment: Oh, I know @Tomalak, that's also why I originally posted mine too, but I believe they don't seem interested in fixing this - and consider it a non-bug - because the problem apparently sits with Markdown itself, not SE (see Jeff's comment on mine).

Comment: @DMA57361 Yeah, the Markdown specification deliberately describes this as being the correct behaviour.

Comment: @TimStone: There's a word for that :P

Comment: @balpha, I added another example, which I *think* is the same issue. (If not, then a rollback is in place.) Do you think that is by-design too? (Real life example [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits/5213#5213).)

Comment: @Arjan Yes. See [my answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121407/115866) for some details. The Markdown converter is working according to spec. If anything, this is a CSS issue.

Comment: Nice reference, @balpha. But `- Sub Item 2a` in the last example above is also surrounded by whitespace but not embedded in `<p>`s in the result...? (Instead: `<ul> <li>Sub Item 2a</li> </ul>`)

Comment: @Arjan Those newlines belong to the outer list. The inner list only has one item.

Comment: True, @balpha (sorry for bothering you), but in the Markdown the inner list *is* surrounded by whitespace too... (I had to add some comments [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/945c4d8e-ebec-42f4-b053-aded47b6db0d/view-source) to get consistent whitespace into [this too long of a list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/5213/10). But of course we know Markdown can't be expected to handle all.)

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the generated HTML, it goes like this:

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li><p>Two</p></li>
<li><p>Three</p></li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

The Two has a blank line below it, so it's a paragraph. The Three has a blank line above it, so it's also a paragraph. Paragraphs on Stack Overflow have bottom margins set.

So a possible temporary fix is to just specify your lists in HTML.

Comment: `So a possible temporary fix is to just specify your lists in HTML.` Grrrrrrrrrrrr...

Comment: OK, but that's not a "we fixed it!" answer :P

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I wish they did... how is that "by design?"

Comment: @minitech: I have no idea. I don't really care whose fault it is; if this bug is blocked on something in Markdown then fine, but that doesn't make it a non-issue and it certainly doesn't make it "by design"; it makes it blocked.