# Spacing in nested list is different from regular spacing

Tags: bug, design, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spacing oddity between lists when lists are found consecutively](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111601/spacing-oddity-between-lists-when-lists-are-found-consecutively)

Why is the spacing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8264986/541686) so small compared to the rest of the answer? Is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: Wanna link to the post where that appears maybe? Kinda hard to tell just from the rendered output. If I had to guess, I'd say there's a extra newline after that bullet item (since that's how [double spacing is supposed to work in lists](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-lists)).

Comment: @Shog9: Sure, here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8264986/541686

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about then. Looks like nested lists don't get the double-spaced goodness.