# Non-changed lines marked as edition

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits

If you would look into the history of last revisions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/715269/gangnus?tab=responses&sort=revisions&StartDate=2012-02-03%2022:14:52Z), in the last revision by Peter Mortensen you'll see strange "changes" of lines into the absolutely same lines. Even twice. Is it a bug? Or I don't see something?

Comment: That link takes me to your profile, actually...

Comment: @Alenanno: Hmmm, I can see it. It seems that somebody's "responses" tab in their profile is only visible to that person and to moderators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He added a line break between each of your lines so they changed from this:

```
 1. We should never mix the different kinds of installations (from PC, from SD). Uninstall one, than install the other.    
 2. The installations from PC and from SD behave differently. That could cause other unwanted effects. We should be aware of it.
```

To this:

```
 1. We should never mix the different kinds of installations (from PC, from SD). Uninstall one, than install the other.

 2. The installations from PC and from SD behave differently. That could cause other unwanted effects. We should be aware of it.
```

Comment: So, maybe it would be better to show linebreaks as changes, repeating the lines says nothing.

Comment: @Gangnus: If you click into the post, then go to its revisions ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9114008/revisions)), then click the icon to display the Markdown diff, you'll see the line break.

Comment: I can get there by your link, but I don't see any such link on the page with question and answers. I see there only link, edit, delete, flag and Add comment. On the page that is after your link, if I press on <>, I see only one green space. Both "edited" lines seem same on the both sides. No difference in line breaks seen. (I use Opera on Linux.)

Comment: It seems, I catched how it is possible to understand if the ends of lines were added. Thank you. But I don't understand how to get into that revisions page to which you kindly gave me the link.

Comment: @Gangnus: When somebody edits your post, you should see "edited x minutes ago" or "edited x hours ago" or something similar - you can click the timestamp and it'll take you to that page.

Comment: Thank you. There is a possibility. But why is it so hidden? How a user could guess that timestamp works as a link to revision page?

Comment: @Gangnus: It's colored blue, so it should be pretty obvious as a link.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. But the link to where? So, even while I knew by your link that the link exists, I couldn't find it.

Comment: You could just click it and find out, or simply mouse over it and see the URL in your browser's status bar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/463/discussion-between-gangnus-and-boltclocks-a-unicorn)

Answer (score 3):

Adding empty lines between list elements wraps the list elements in `<p>` tags (see the first few paragraphs in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74115/115866) for some discussion on that).

```
1. First point
2. Second point
```

turns into

```
<ol>
    <li>First point</li>
    <li>Second point</li>
</ol>
```

while

```
1. First point

2. Second point
```

is converted to

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <p>First point</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Second point</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

So from an HTML perspective, the contents of the list elements were indeed changed in a major way; hence this is very much by design. That's why the [revisions list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9114008/revisions) also offers a Markdown diff view; sometimes it's more helpful to see the changes to the source than to the rendered version.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have already found the use of "source". Simple <> button won't help much. What is it for?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: On the revision page there is a button with <> on a little page. "show the markdown source side by side". But it doesn't show markdown as I see. Oh, sorry. The "source" link does not, too, really. Too bad.