# Edit revision: markdown source won't work?

Tags: support, markdown, revisions-list

On the revision page there is a button with <> on a little page. "show the markdown source side by side" I don't see any markdown there.

As I understand, I should see there tags as in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121407/176427)? But I see no traces of any tags.

I use Opera on Linux
As example revisions was taken [the post here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9114008/revisions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it says *[Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) source*, not HTML source.

```
*This* is **Markdown**.

And <em>this</em> is <strong>HTML</strong>, with the tags and all.
```

See the [editing help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and the [Markdown syntax documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Comment: So, it shows only tags that I have written there by hand?

Comment: @Gangnus It shows the differences between the raw text of the two revisions. If you used some of the [allowed HTML tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) instead of Markdown syntax, you'd see them in this view as well.